# Ionicons not displaying in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, firefox, ionicons

I have researched all day but can't find an answer as to why my ionicons fail to display in IE and Firefox but successfully display in chrome.

My site is built in Bootstrap 3 and the Ionicon CSS is called in the header after the other CSS files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.4.1/css/ionicons.min.css"></link>
```

When I launch the site in IE (all versions) and Firefox (all versions) the Ionicons are displayed as small rectangles with two rows and two characters each.

If you're using Firefox you can see the [error here](http://aliensix.com/creativ) in the Team section where the social Ionicons should be.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this? I have tried a few solutions from this site with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't installed them correctly, follow steps below.

1. Download and extract the font pack
2. Copy the ionicons.css to your project
3. Copy the fonts folder to your project
4. Ensure the font urls within ionicons.css properly reference the
   fonts path within your project.
5. Include a reference to the ionicons.css file from every webpage you
   need to use it.

Taken from [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons), this should sort out your problem!

Comment: It wont fix that way. Maybe you re using the cdn version? . Have a look to this (old?) issue thread. https://github.com/driftyco/ionicons/issues/8